# DashClockExtension services always run

Tags: android, android-service, dashclock

According to the ProcStats screen DashClockExtension services are never stopped.
Isn't it wasteful? Is there a way to implement an extension so that the system can kill it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to keep DashClock extensions from always running in the background; this is a limitation of the DashClock API design. My bad.